# Does retrofit makes requests on destroyed fragment?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, request, retrofit

I use retrofit, and I have 2 fragments (Fragment A, Fragment B). In each fragment I have 2 request (For fragment A the request let's call request A1, requestA2). So I open my app and opens Fragment A. After this asynchronously starts request A1 and request A2. So After this I'll open Fragment B and there goes request too. (request B1 and B2). But If I'll open Fragment B and I'll click back button fast to return fragment A, will be the request B1 and B2 continue to work asynchronously? Or retrofit automatically cancels the request on fragment destroy? So am I need to write something like this on back press?

```
if(call != null) {
  call.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I set logs, and after clicking back, the log continues to print. So I think this can cause performance problems.

Comment: In short . **Yes** retrofit call will persist even if you change the fragment . if you don't want to then you have to cancel it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as i know retrofit don't do that and you must first create call as global variable in both fragments and cancel the call every  where you think you don't need that call anymore or you want to cancel and renew that call.

```
private Call<Response> mCall;
//...onCreateView() and other codes
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if(mCall!= null && mCall.isExecuted()) {
        mCall.cancel();
    }
}
```

And check it in `onFailure()` of retrofit for prevent some bugs that happens for me

```
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
      if (call.isCanceled()) {
           //do nothing 
      }else {
           //show some thing to user ui
      }
}
```